# virtual environment name problem in django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-testing, django-errors, django-runserver

I wanted to start Virtual environment again after closing it before but by mistake i wrote my project name(the projectname which we create in django after installing django with using django-admin startproject) instead of virtual environment name that i've created.

I wrote this - py -m venv schoolMS
and Was expecting this - py -m venv myschool
and now terminal showing error - Error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\My Study\Sem 6\Project\myschool\Scripts\python.exe'
like this how can i solve the problem?